# Database-first EF7-7.0.0-rc1-final dnx ef dbcontext scaffold command fails

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, entity-framework-core

I am using this command:

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=webuat08,1433,Database=Store;user    
id=user_here;password=password_here" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer
```

The database "Store" exists. But I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to identify the primary key for table 'dbo.spt_fallback_db'.
Unable to generate entity type for table 'dbo.spt_fallback_db'.
Unable to identify the primary key for table 'dbo.spt_fallback_dev'.
Unable to generate entity type for table 'dbo.spt_fallback_dev'.
Unable to identify the primary key for table 'dbo.spt_fallback_usg'.
Unable to generate entity type for table 'dbo.spt_fallback_usg'.
Could not find type mapping for column 
'dbo.MSreplication_options.optname'     with data type 'sysname'. Skipping column.
Unable to identify the primary key for table 'dbo.MSreplication_options'.
Unable to generate entity type for table 'dbo.MSreplication_options'.
Unable to identify the primary key for table 'dbo.spt_monitor'.
Unable to generate entity type for table 'dbo.spt_monitor'.
Done
```

If I change the name of the Database in the command to a DB that doesn't exist I still get the same error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your schema e.g. the SQL you used to create your tables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the primary key in your tables